# Why do we have multiple declarations for main in C?

Tags: c

C does not support function overloading. How can we then have 3 prototypes for main?
What is the historical reason for having 3 prototypes?

Comment: The answer to your question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define/5296593#5296593

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are only two prototypes for `main` that a standard-conforming C implementation is required to recognize: `int main(void)` and `int main(int, char *[])`. This is not overloading, since there can still only be one `main` per program; having a `void foo(int, double)` in one program and a `char *foo(FILE *)` in another isn't overloading either.

The reason for the two prototypes is convenience: some applications want command-line arguments, while others don't bother with them.

All other prototypes, such as `void main(void)` and `int main(int, char *[], char *[])`, are compiler/platform-dependent extensions.

Comment: There are only two _canonical_ forms of `main` and the second also has the text "or equivalent" tacked on (so `char**` is okay). In addition, the standard also _explicitly_ allows others - it just doesn't mandate them.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I decided not to bother with equivalent forms since they're already handled by other rules in the standard. Thanks for the other remark, added "required" to the answer.

Comment: This only answers how it works on a hosted system. For a complete answer check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define/5296593#5296593