# What are, and what is the difference between, kmain and dmain -- main functions in C?

Tags: c, kernel

As the title says, what are they and what's the difference?

Some examples:

`dmain`:

```
void dmain(void* mbd, unsigned int magic)
```

`kmain`:

```
void kmain( void* mbd, unsigned int magic )
```

P.S. I found a similar post here but it was about `wmain`:

[What is the difference between wmain and main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438049/what-is-the-difference-between-wmain-and-main)

Also `_tmain`:

[What is the difference between _tmain() and main() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c)

__

They take the same arguments but is there a difference? And any links to some info this so I could learn is appreciated, google yielded weird results...

Also, is there an official sort of like 'man' pages of C?

Comment: Don't know about _man pages_ for C, but there is the ISO/IEC C standard 'C99'. This URL has a link to the latest version of the C99 standard: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/standards

Comment: As these are non standard functions/"main" functions, you have to tell us where you found these.

Comment: These are implementation defined, Have a look at my answer here: [What these C's main function indicates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091711/what-these-cs-main-function-indicates)

Comment: the dmain and kmain are from kernel code, one's from: http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones#kernel.c  Which gives a limited explanation. Finding _tmain and wmain just made me more confused...

Comment: Well... from that wiki it seems that kmain is the entry point of the kernel. I do not know what you want to know about it? (I *suppose* that the real `main()` is hidden in kmain.cpp, see example listing, but this is just my speculation)

Comment: @krack krackerz There's nothing special in C about a kmain or dmain function. However the people at osdev.org wrote their bootloader so it starts running the kmain function in their code.

Comment: so essentially I could make up my own name for main. How about calling it "primary"? Also, since main is an object, does this mean that it isnt in this example anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be referring to [this tutorial on OSDev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones).

If you’ll notice, this is *not* a standard C program with `main()` as its entry point. In fact, the page shows *two* entry points: one written in Assembler in a way for GRUB to find & load, and which sets up & loads the second, `kmain()`, which is written in C. The writers use the name `kmain` to mean “kernel main”; presumably `dmain` is the entry point for drivers & would stand for “driver main”.

C makes a distinction between “freestanding” and “hosted” implementations. Hosted is what you’re probably more familiar with; the standard C library is available, and all programs start at the `main` function.

OS kernels are (often) good examples of freestanding environments. The C library will likely *not* be available, for example (except for certain headers like `stddef.h` & `stdarg.h`; see the standard for details). Also, the entry point is not defined by the standard anymore.  The OSDev.org tutorial is making a special point of that fact, by explicitly defining its entry point with a different name.

You could probably run the tutorial renaming `kmain` to `main`, but note that it’s still `void main(void*, unsigned int)`, *not* `int main(int, char**)`; in fact that sort of confusion is likely part of the reason the writers chose to use a different name. But is is just a convention they’ve selected, not anything standardized.

Comment: so essentially I could make up my own name for main. How about calling it "primary"?

Comment: Careful: In this restricted case, where you control the start-up code, you can make up your own name. Such is generally not the case, though.