# Bit fields in C. Explain the values of S.a and S.b

Tags: c

Consider following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct mystruct
{
    int a:1;
    int b:2;
    int c:3;
};

void main()
{
    struct mystruct S;
    clrscr();
    S.a=1;
    S.b=-5;
    S.c=100;
    printf("%d %u %d %u %d %u",S.a,S.a,S.b,S.b,S.c,S.c);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: i am new and dont know how to ask a question in stackoverflow..... i wanted to ask the beahviou of bit fields but now i know the answer thanks.

Comment: @ShankarBhatnagar Surprisingly, it works just the same way as when you ask questions to other people in the real world.

Comment: `void main()` is wrong; it should be `int main(void)`. If your textbook told you to use `void main()`, please find a better one.

Comment: @Lundin i meant that i put my question based on this code in the 'title' part. See top to find the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson [Not necessarily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define/5296593#5296593) although in this particular case, it is quite certain that we are dealing with a hosted application, so you are correct.

Comment: @Eregrith: find the question at the top , in the TITLE (above the advertisement) :)

Answer (score 2):

You're defining a 1-bit signed number `a`. That doesn't make a lot of sense, since there's no bits left for anything once the sign has been encoded. Small bitfields should typically be of an `unsigned` type, and fields of width `1` must be, then you can store 0 or 1 which is probably what you meant.

The same problem happens with the `b` member, it's only two bits wide but you're trying to store `-5`, which really doesn't encode in two bits very easily.

Comment: i already got my answer by running and repeatedly modifying my code. thanks! :)

Comment: "You're defining a 1-bit signed number `a`" -- Not necessarily. The signedness of a bit field declared as `int` is implementation-defined. Use `signed int` if you want a signed bit field, or `unsigned int` if you want an unsigned bit field (which is almost always what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Statements `S.b = -5` and `S.c = 100` will cause an overflow (since you are assigning values that cannot be held in 2 or 3 bits), and hence S.b and S.c won't contain the value you expect them to.