# program hangs after inputting array

Tags: c, pointers, alloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
//#include<alloc.h>

int* mergeSort(int*,int);
int* merge(int*,int*,int);

void main()
{
  int n;int i=0;
  int *a,*b;

  scanf("%d",&n);
  a=(int)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
  for(;i<n;i++)
     scanf("%d",&a[i]);

  b=mergeSort(a,n);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     printf("%d ",b[i]);

}

int* mergeSort(int *b,int n)
{
  int temp,*s;

  if(n>2)
  {
     mergeSort(b,n/2);
     mergeSort(b+n/2,n-n/2);
     s=merge(b,b+n/2,n);

     return s;
  }
  else if(n==2)
  {
     if(b[0]>b[1])
     {
         temp=b[0];
         b[0]=b[1];
         b[1]=temp; 
     }
     return;
  }
}

int* merge(int* a,int* c,int n)
{
  int i=0,j=0,k=0,
  int* x;

  while( (j ! =n/2) && (k != (n-n/2)) && (i < n))
  {
       if(a[j]<c[k])
       {
             x[i]=a[j];
             j++; 
             i++;
       }
       else
       {
             x[i]=c[k];
             k++;
             i++;
       }
   }
   for( ; j<n/2; j++,i++)
      x[i]=a[j];

   for( ; k < (n-n/2); k++,i++)
      x[i]=c[k];

   return x;
}
```

when i run this code,it hangs after inputting all the elements of the array in first for loop. Please help me, how can i correct it to make it work successfully? it hangs on calling the mergeSort function from main() function.

Comment: @Shark Obsolete DOS-only header.

Comment: This is quite scary code. As a side comment, please [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: debug debug debug debug!

Comment: conio.h  => Console Input/Output

Comment: Furthermore, coding style, indentation and whitespace please!

Comment: Now that it's formatted, i'd say your recursion never ends so if you let it run long enough you should hit a stackoverflow.

Other than that, saying "my code halts after inputing elements" isn't helping much, put some prinfs to localize WHERE it hangs, and then we can figure out why... @H2CO3: thanks.

Comment: 1) The `mergeSort()` function has code paths that don't return a value. 2) The `merge()` function uses an uninitialized pointer (`int *x`). There may be other problems but I stopped looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`it hangs after inputting all the elements of the array in first for loop.`

***hangs***? Are you sure... that's pretty good considering your merge code declares a pointer to an int:

```
int *x;
```

and never initializes it, then tries to jump to an offset (`i`) past it:

```
x[i]=a[j];
```

Change your code to this:

```
int *x = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

and it should stop crashing/hanging whatever.

FYI, whenever you `malloc()` you should `free()` right now you have memory leaks.

Comment: thank you so much...now its working fine after initializing the int *x as you suggested and thank you @blastfurnace

Comment: @mike....can you please help in doing this merge sort with recursion...this code doesnot give the right answer...please help me!

Comment: @yodh - yeah, I noticed that too, it's close, but not quite right. Have you debugged it at all? Do you have any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: yeah i've debugged it...and its running fine but the thing is it is still not giving the right answer.

Comment: @yodh - debugging doesn't just mean making it compile ;) It means analyzing logic errors too. What I mean is you say it's not giving the right answer, so what analysis do you have to show that? What sets of input don't give the right answer, when you say it's "wrong" is it all out of order or only a particular subset of the whole? is it `merge()` or `mergesort()` that is giving the wrong data? (I'm guessing `merge()`) If it's `merge()` then is the data correct after the `while()` loop but wrong before the `for()`?

Comment: @yodh - See what I'm saying? You can step with a debuger or printf data as you go to analyze where the failure is occuring. That's "debugging" your program. Even if you can't seem to to get the correct output, you can figure out what inputs caues bad behavior, and what function/area the problem is in.

Comment: hehe...i dint know how to debug the logical errors...thanks for this and now i'll try to do it this way.... :) and hope i succeed this time!

Comment: @yodh no problem. Once you've done some analysis, if you still can't find it feel free to post another question asking specifically why your merge sort isn't sorting and provide your debug analysis, I or others would be happy to help follow up on your leg work.

Comment: thanks :) i want to ask one thing as you said above that i should free the allocated memory at the end...but doesnt the program itself releases that memory after it ends?!

Comment: @yodh - C programs *do not* do memory management by themselves. The Operating System you're on *may* do this for you, but that's not guaranteed... and if you ever work on embedded projects or on computers with no MMU (memory management unit) there's almost a guarantee that they **will not** do the clean up for you. So it's a good habit and good style to free your memory and close handles when you're done with them.

Comment: yes i did some analysis on this code...and i am posting the output that suggests its working all well except at a single step...just before merging all elements! i'll show you with the code and its output below as a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some things wrong, not only basic things like `void main` instead of `int main` but also eg the `return;` in `mergeSort()` which should return `int*` and the uninitialized `x`. Also one important thing about the algorithm: You seem to assume that `n` is a power of 2: you recursively divide by 2 and assume that it always is an untruncated integer.

Comment: It might be fine for main to return void, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define/5296593#5296593). Although most likely, this case is a hosted program and then your comment about main is correct.

Comment: but i've taken (n-n/2) the second time...so even if its truncated i'll get the rest of the elements second time...wont i?

Comment: Right. I overlooked that. But please consider the other points I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the code doesn't compile in a C++ compiler (I know it's C code, but still...),

a couple of problems are:

line 11:

```
a=(int)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

why are you casting a pointer to an int? a is an int *

line 38:

```
return;
```

you are returning from mergeSort without a return value...that can't be good

I recommend that you fix all the compiler errors and warnings, then try again

Comment: actually i was not getting any compile time errors but run time error...and yes after removing int casting, and initializing *x my code is working fine, not giving correct result though.