# Input using gets not working, but working with scanf

Tags: c, gcc, input, stdin

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
  char str[100];
  char letter;
  letter=getchar();
  printf("%c",letter);
  gets(str);
  //Rest of code
}
```

On execution, the code skips the gets(str) line. But when I replace gets by scanf, it works. Any specific reason why that doesnt work?
I am using gcc 4.7.2.

Answer (score 6):

The first call to getchar() leaves a newline character in the input buffer. The next call `gets()` considers that newline as end of input and hence doesn't wait for you to input.

Consume the newline character using another getchar().

```
 ...
 letter=getchar();
 getchar(); // To consume a newline char left
 printf("%c",letter);
 fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
```

**Note:** `gets()` is dangerous as its vulnerable against buffer overflow. So use **[fgets()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html)** instead.

Comment: So is there any way i can make gets() ignore the newline...or perhaps remove the newline from the buffer.
PS: I tried using fflush but then also faced the same issue

Comment: You can use getchar() once more to consume it. I updated my answer. fflush(stdin) works only on MSVS and it's undefined behaviour on other compilers/platforms.

Answer (score 2):

as answered above when you read a character from statndard input the enter you hit after this is placed in stdin buffer which was read by `gets()` in your case . that is  why `gets()` is not waiting for input.

you can use `fflush(stdin)` to clear the input buffer after reading the character .

Answer (score 1):

`getchar()` leaves a trailing line feed character `'\n'` in stdin. When you call `gets()`, it reads until it encounters such a line feed character, which it discards. Since the first character it reads is `'\n'`, it immediately stops there.

The solution is to make a dummy read to discard the line feed character:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[100];
  char letter;

  letter=getchar();
  getchar();

  printf("%c",letter);

  gets(str);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Please note that `void main()` is not valid C (unless you are developing a free running  embedded system, which seems unlikely in this case). More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define/5296593#5296593).

Please note that the `gets()` function is no longer part of the C language, it was removed with the C11 version of the standard. Use `fgets()` instead.