# c program is bypassing gets()

Tags: c, string, gets

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int N,i,j,n,*numArray,count=0;
char **arr,*part1,*part2,*token;
scanf("%d",&N);
arr=(char **)malloc(N*sizeof(char *));
numArray=(int *)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
arr[i]=(char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
}

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
printf("plz enter %d th :",i);
    gets(&arr[i][0]);// why is it not executing

}

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
 printf("%s",arr[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

I tried executing this code and found that the line gets(&arr[i][0]); does not get executed, i.e. it doesn't wait for user to input. Instead, it prints "plz enter 0 th: plz enter 1 th: plz enter 2 th: and so on" and doesn't wait for user to enter the string.
I am unable to get what exactly is wrong and what exactly is happening? Plese help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `newline` left in buffer.

Comment: And what value does `scanf()` return?  You need to check that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle scanf() in this program let user inter number of sentences

Comment: We understand that.  The question is what is the return value of the `scanf` function?  If it returns 0, it didn't read anything.  Also, what is your input when you get this behavior?

Comment: @dbush when i enter 3 (i.e. N=3), the output that i get is: plz enter 0 th: plz enter 1 th: plz enter 2 th:, this means that scanf is reading value for N successfully and is not returning 0

Comment: @SouravGhosh thanks for the downvote :)

Comment: @gj1103 Just because I left a comment, I become the downvoter? :))

Comment: I venture to suggest putting `[c] gets skips line` in a search box will yield some insight into the problem (this question has *many* duplicates, but most are so arbitrarily titled it's ridiculous).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input using gets not working, but working with scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300121/input-using-gets-not-working-but-working-with-scanf)

Comment: `gets` is not standard C (anymore). **Never ever** use it! Use `fgets` on `stdin` instead. And check the values provides from external input before using them and functions for errors which are relevant for the program execution. Never rely on correct input data!

Comment: And if you need a 2D array, use one! Your code does not have anything which can relresent a 2D array.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding of code, by us humans, 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line. 2) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'. suggest using 4 spaces (never tabs) for each indent level. 3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  4) use meaningful variable names. A variable name should indicate usage or content (or better, both).

Comment: the expression `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  So all that expression, in the call to `malloc()` is doing is cluttering the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )  The posted code will cause the compiler to output a long string of warning messages (12 warnings with `gcc) that need to be fixed.

Comment: amongst other things, the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>`  so the `malloc()` function is properly defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line inputing the number of entries

```
scanf("%d",&N);
```

leaves a `newline` in the input buffer. Then this line

```
gets(&arr[i][0]);
```

takes that lone `newline` as the first entry.

You can get rid of it like this

```
scanf("%d%*c",&N);
```

But you should not be using `gets` in this day and age, it is obsolete. This would have been better for the string entries (instead of the above mod)

```
scanf("%50s", arr[i]);
```

as well as checking the return value from all the `scanf` calls. The code still needs improvemnt though, since as stated `scanf` will only scan up to the first whitespace.

Comment: its unbelievable! has been too long since i started coding in c and its the first time I face this situation. Its tough to digest for me that why I never faced this before. Also please suggest what to use in place of that? scanf("%[^\n]*c",&arr[i][0])

Comment: I hate `scanf`. I would rather use `fgets` and remove the trailing `newline`. But the main point is not to mix your input methods. AFAIK you would use `scanf("%50[^\n]",arr[i])` but that's a guess as it's not a syntax I use.

Comment: but the fact that i met this situation dissappointed me. I am unable to digest. Thanks @weather

Comment: this line: `scanf("%d",&N);` leaves white space in stdin.  Suggest using: `scanf("%d ",&N);`.  Notice the trailing space in the format string.

Comment: @user3629249 unfortunately that only works (MSVC) if you want the next input at the same time. `scanf("%d ",&N);` does not return until the following input is also given.

Comment: @WeatherVane Could you please help me by answering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764258/why-character-pointer-is-getting-assigned-just-a-character-while-a-string-is-su?noredirect=1#comment62997129_37764258

Answer (score 2):

> . it doesn't wait for user to input. Instead, it prints "plz enter 0
>   th: plz enter 1 th: plz enter 2 th: and so on"

this is due to problem of **white space** in your loop... instead try consuming them before every time you scan string using `scanf(" ");`, like this :

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
printf("plz enter %d th :",i);
    scanf(" "); //to consume white spaces
    gets(arr[i]);// why is it not executing? because of wrong arguments

}
```

---

**EDIT** : *as suggested by @user3629249*

> Never use `gets()` for two major reasons:
>
> 1. It allows the input to overflow the input buffer
> 2. It is removed from the language from C11 onward.

a better alternative would be `fgets()`

and here's a link to know about it more: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309845/5281962)

Comment: aren't arr[i] and &arr[i][0] same... as &arr[i][0] is nothing but &(*arr[i]+0)...

Comment: the info about white space is good, but NEVER use `gets()` for two major reasons: 1) it allows the input to overflow the input buffer 2) it is removed from the language from `C11` onward.

Comment: Thanks for the info @user3629249 can i add that info to the answer ?

Comment: @CherubimAnand,  Naturally, you can always edit your own answer.

Comment: @user3629249 I know i could edit but just waited for your consent to use the info you provided :)