# how to see which function is assigned to function pointer at run time..?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int add(int i,int j)
{
        printf("\n%s\n",__FUNCTION__);

        return (i*j);
}

int (*fp)(int,int);

void main()
{
        int j=2;
        int i=5;

        printf("\n%s\n",__FUNCTION__);

        fp=add;

        printf("\n%d\n",(*fp)(2,5));
        printf("\n%s\n",*fp);
}
```

Comment: What is 'void main' and why is this tagged c++?

Comment: @nijansen With proper compiler settings, `void main()` is another compilation error :)

Comment: At run time, the names of functions are not known unless you stash them someplace. The linker just makes sure every reference to `add` refers to the same place, but the name "add" is not kept unless you specifically keep it.

Comment: @nijansen `main` is where a program starts. `void main()` is an implementation-specific way to write the main function in a freestanding environment, fully compliant with the C standard. [More info here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define/5296593#5296593)

Answer (score 4):

You can compare the function pointer with a pointer to function. Like this :

```
    if (fp==add)
        printf("\nadd\n");
```

There are no other (standard) ways<sup>**1**</sup>.

This

```
printf("\n%s\n",*fp);
```

is a compilation error.

---

There are platform specific ways. For linux, this works :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <execinfo.h>

int add(int i,int j)

{

        printf("\n%s\n",__FUNCTION__);

        return (i*j);

}

int (*fp)(int,int);

union
{
    int (*fp)(int,int);
    void* fp1;
} fpt;

int main()
{
        fp=add;


        fpt.fp=fp;

        char ** funName = backtrace_symbols(&fpt.fp1, 1);
        printf("%s\n",*funName);
}
```

Comment: There are other ways, it's just very difficult—you have to parse the executable's symbol table and look up the address there.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Those are platform specific (like a trick with backtrace). I meant, there are no standard ways

Comment: @BЈовић On linux "-rdynamic" option needs to be passed to gcc to get the names of the functions.