# how to jump back to the top of a program

Tags: c

I have a large block of code inside main and would like to return to the top of main and run through again if a certain variable in 'code' is true. How would I do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{

// if varable in code is true return to here



//code
//
//
//


}
```

Comment: `while - continue` loop?

Comment: Just call `main();` again? (Watch out for infinite recursion)

Comment: `TOP:` ... `if (variable) goto TOP;`

Comment: @Kninnug explicitly calling `main()` is not allowed by the C standard.

Comment: @Ben calling `main` is allowed in C, but not in C++. But it doesn't look like a good design for this problem.

Comment: `void main(void)` is not C standard, it should be `int main(void)` with `return 0`.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk That is not correct. [More info here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define/5296593#5296593)

Comment: `DOINGITWRONG:` ... `if(broken) goto DOINGITWRONG;`

Comment: @Lundin Standard says *It shall be defined with a return type of int*.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk Read that link again. It does indeed say so, in a subclause of the chapter _hosted environment_. If your C program is not running in a hosted environment, it may return anything.

Comment: @Lundin We don't know if his program will be running in a hosted environment or not. Please also notice that he is a beginner. I think it's better to advice him to write `int main(void)`. You also have done it in your answer ;)

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk If you don't know, then you cannot give advise. There are countless of embedded systems beginners out there and there is no telling what system this person is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the code from `main()` and put it in a function:

```
static void my_function(void)
{
  /* lots of stuff here */
}
```

Then just call it:

```
int main(void)
{
  my_function();
  if(condition)
    my_function();
  return 0;
}
```

This is way cleaner than using a loop, in my opinion, since the use case was not really "loop-like". If you want to do something once or twice, break it out into a function then call the function once or twice. As a bonus, it also gives you a great opportunity to introduce a name (the function name) for the thing that your program is doing, which helps make the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

```
int main(void)
{
  int gotostart=0; 
  // if varable 'gotostart' in code is true return to here
  beginning:

  // code [...]

  if(gotostart)
    goto beginning;

  return 0;
}
```

as Armen has rightly pointed out, `goto` deserves some warning. the most popular ist Dijsktra's [GOTO statements considered harmful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful), as it is somewhat counterproductive to structured programming.

a more structured approach would be:

```
int main(void)
{
  int gotostart=0; 

  do { // if varable 'gotostart' in code is true return to here

    // code [...]

  } while(gotostart)

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer but unless you warn against using goto and provide a more structured alternative, you will keep receiving downvotes

Comment: There really is no good reason to suggest `goto` for this problem when there are perfectly good alternatives, also see [GOTO still considered harmful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)

Comment: The second solution will never execute the code in the loop. Either use a `do .. while` loop or initialize `gotostart` to `1`

Answer (score 2):

```
int main (void)
{
  bool keep_looping = true;

  while (keep_looping)
  {
    // code

    if(done_with_stuff)
    {
      keep_looping = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good, except a while/do-while loop only checks at the beginning/end of the loop, a goto can check at multiple points.  Probably could use a continue/break example.

Comment: @technosaurus If you need to check at multiple points, something in your program design is likely flawed. In that case you should implement the program as a state machine (switch statement or array of function pointers).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you are talking about would probably to use the while loop as mentioned but do this:

```
while(true){
    if(something){
     continue;
     } // then use break when you want to leave the loop all together
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your program repeats ever the same schema, then a `while()` loop is the best approach.
But if your program is a little cumbersome, perhaps you would prefer a `goto` statement, in order to jump to the **label** you desire:

```
  int main(void) {
            // Initial stuff

      jump_point:

           // Do more stuff

      if (some-condition)
           goto jump_point;

           // ... ...

      return 0;
  }
```

I think you should have to design your program in a way that a natural and clear loop is executed:

```
  int main(void) {

       while(terminate-condition-is-false) {

           // Do all your stuff inside this loop

      }

      return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a `goto` statement:

```
//Assume here is your starting point of your program
start: //we have declared goto statement for beginning


//Assume here is your ending point
goto start; //Here is that show go back to first position
```