# How to make gcc happy about embedded systems and void main(void)

Tags: c, language-lawyer

[C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.1.2.2.1 says

> it [main()] shall be defined with a return type of **int**

However, section 6.7.4 introduces the **_Noreturn** keyword, which seems to be very useful for the `main()` of bare-bone embedded systems.

What is the most elegant way to declare a non-returnable main()? Is it `_Noreturn int main(void)`?

Comment: What is the point of this? Why not just use `int main(void)`? It's standard, portable and non-gcc specific.

Comment: @user694733 Because he is using a barebone embedded system where 1) `int main (void)` doesn't make any sense and 2) `void main (void)` is 100% standard and 100% portable. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define/5296593#5296593).

Comment: (...and then people keep up-voting the comment of some confused PC programmer. Wish you could down vote comments.)

Comment: It's embedded - who cares if it's never going to return anyway.  I just don't understand the concern at all.  It's a non-issue, surely?

Comment: @MartinJames, 1) intent, 2) sometimes saving a couple of bytes does matter. It's a very small issue, I confess.

Comment: @Lundin Except that I am **not** PC programmer, but embedded systems programmer, and so far toolchains have worked with `int main(void)` in freestanding systems just fine, and compilers have worked it out.

Comment: @Lundin It seems you are right about standard allowing other return types than `int`. `void main(void)` is not 100% portable though (IAR arm compiler for example).

Comment: @MartinJames Usually, bare bone embedded systems start execution from a reset ISR, which in turn calls main. If the calling convention of main is `int main()` then the reset ISR will make room for the return value on the stack, even though main() will never return.

Comment: @user694733 It will probably work, not because the compiler "worked it out", but rather because you sacrifice some bytes on the stack, for no reason (you create a memory leak on the stack). If you are on a low-end 8-bit MCU with a limited stack, this will matter a lot. On a larger system, less so.

Comment: @Lundin No. In IAR for example, `int main(void)` is the *only* supported form, so it wasn't me that made the "sacrifice". But as compiler in question is smart enough, it treats `main` as special function, and not reserve those useless bytes on stack. That's what I meant with "working it out". But at least we could agree that there is no 100% portable `main` function when it comes to embedded world.

Answer (score 3):

You are reading the wrong part of the standard. 5.1.2.2.1 is a subclause of **5.1.2.2 Hosted environment**. A barebone embedded system is **not** a hosted system, it is a freestanding system. So the cited text is irrelevant. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define/5296593#5296593).

The most portable way to declare main in a freestanding environment is `void main (void)`.

As already mentioned in another answer, the gcc compiler option is `-ffreestanding`

Answer (score 1):

Your objectives are contradictory. You cannot ask for a compiler flag that is not compiler specific.

That said, for gcc it is: `-ffreestanding`.

> `-ffreestanding`
>
> ```
> Assert that compilation takes place in a freestanding environment.
>  This implies `-fno-builtin'.  A freestanding environment is one in
>  which the standard library may not exist, and program startup may
>  not necessarily be at `main'.  The most obvious example is an OS
>  kernel.  This is equivalent to `-fno-hosted'.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the end of the phrase *"or in some other implementation-defined manner"*. So your *implementation*, that is your platform, not you as a programmer, may foresee a different return type of `main`, and some platforms do.

Also according to C99 and C11, you are not forced to specify a return value for `main`. The platform is supposed to do reasonable things, when you return from `main`, if you do it ever.

In any case, `main` is special and obeys special rules. Trust your platform provider that it does the right thing for it. You are talking of a completely negligible optimization, in case your `main` really does never return.

Comment: No, he is reading the wrong chapter of the standard. The phrase about "implementation-defined manner" applies to the _parameters_ of main in a _hosted_ system and thus it is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Lundin You're right that it applies to hosted systems, but not that it only applies to the parameters of `main`. This is why 5.1.2.2.3 (still part of 5.1.2.2) starts with "If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int".

Comment: @hvd 5.1.2.2.3 ends with `If the return type is not compatible with int, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified`. Unspecified and impl.defined are two different things. This might actually be an inconsistency in the C standard. _However_, it doesn't matter since this question isn't about hosted systems.

Comment: @Lundin I see no inconsistency. Whether `void main(void)` is valid at all is implementation-defined. If it's valid, a program uses it, and the program stops by returning from `main`, the termination status is unspecified. They are two different things, so one can be implementation-defined while the other is unspecified. Agreed that it doesn't matter for this question, commenting anyway because it may still be of interest.

Comment: @lundin, no I don't think that it only applies to the parameters. The whole phrase starts *"It shall be defined with a return type of `int`.."* and the semicolon and "or" referes to the whole phrase that is before it. As you can see from the non-caps that are used after it, the ":" doesn't terminate the phrase.