# what is the meaning of main(i) in C, and how does it work? and what is the value and type of i?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

```
void main(i)
{
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

what is meaning of `main(i)` here and how it works? and what is value and type of `i`?

Comment: Use signature `int main...`

Comment: When i tried it with the gcc compiler it is giving 1 as output

Answer (score 5):

```
void main(i)
```

Declaring a function parameter with no type is only valid in the old, obsolete C90 standard. In C90 `i` would then default to type `int`.

If this code was for a freestanding implementation (embedded system or OS), it would have been valid in C90. It would be equivalent to `void main (int i)`. Your compiler is required to document what this form of main() is supposed to do.

If this code was for a hosted implementation (programming running on an OS), it is not valid and will not compile. C90 2.1.2.2 Hosted environment only allows two forms of main():

```
int main(void) 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

In newer C standards, the code will be invalid no matter if freestanding or hosted, as the "default to int" rule has been removed from the language.

Answer (score 3):

It's *possibly* of type `int`, and represents the number of arguments passed on the command line; including the name of the program.

But you should not write the `main` prototype like that as formally the program behaviour is implementation-defined and so can vary from platform to platform.

Use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` instead.

Comment: Not using those two forms of main (for a hosted system) is not undefined, it is implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: Changed it blindly: can't verify right now - in a meeting in which I should be paying attention.

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

```
void main(i)
{
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

is *invalid* syntax in `C`, you should not use it, because, `C` standard says

1. Case 1: [`C11`, §5.1.2.2.1 ], in a hosted environment,

   - `main()` should return `int`
   - it shall take either 0 (`void`) or 2 (`int argc, char*argv[]` or equivalent) arguments.
2. Case 2: In a freestanding environment,

   - it is invalid (as per the latest standard), because the "variable type default to `int`" concept has been no longer supported by `C` standard.

---

*[This is just for understanding, not supported any more in the standards and hence, the behaviour is not guaranteed.]*

Now, coming to the *meaning* part for the above code, it is a **hacky and obsolete** way to provide the definition of `i` in `main()`, mainly used in *[code golfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)* to shorten the code size. The type of `i` defaults to `int` here, and holds the number of augments (including the program name) supplied  to the program.

So, for example, if the program is run like

```
 ./test
```

in the program, `i` is *most likely* to have a value of `1`.

Comment: It is invalid because implicit int has been removed from the language. It is not invalid for the reasons stated here. Furthermore you quote the _hosted_ implementation chapter, nothing in the question indicates that this is a hosted system.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the correction. Will update accordingly. Also sir, in freestanding the `main()` itself needs not to be named `main()`, isn't it?

Comment: Nope, it could be named anything.

Comment: Problem is, C99 and C11 have the clause "or in some other implementation-defined manner" which could be interpreted in two ways: either that the arguments of main() are allowed to differ (I made that interpretation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define/5296593#5296593)) or that the whole form of main might be different (such as for example Windows' WinMain function).

Comment: @Lundin Absolutely right sir. Just my personal opining, till date I used to read it like _"....and with no parameters....or with two parameters...or in some other implementation-defined manner"_, so I believed that it is talking about the parameters only, but now I see your point. it appears ambiguous.

Comment: When i tried it with the gcc compiler it is giving 1 as output