# Returning a value on function exit in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, iso

Is it true that in C++ `main ()` is not required to include a `return 0;`?

Does it apply to `main` only or to any non-void function?

Is it new in C++11 or was it always like that?

What is the rationale?

Comment: "not required" != "should not"

Comment: It's used all the time, what do you mean actually? It's not necessary for `main()` to do so.

Comment: Its up to you, it optional.

Comment: So, why should I include it if it's not `required`? Just curious.

Comment: My question is more precisely; Why the standard committee decided to do so?

Comment: now edited. Thanks

Comment: @Amadeus read my comment above: Why the standard committee decided to ignore the return in main in ISO C++?

Comment: Why the downvoting, people? Genuinely curious here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define/5296593#5296593

Comment: @m.rossi _"Why the downvoting, people?"_ 1st of all make your question self contained, posting that link containing the essential information as a 1st comment is probably not the best idea for asking here.

Comment: Got it @πάνταῥεῖ, I was not sure about that really, I wanted to ask to the SO community anyway, sorry

Comment: @mrossi - I edited your q. slighly in an attempt to make it clearer. Pls check if it is okay.

Comment: It's true, and it's always been like that. `main` is special in C++. E.g. you cannot call it.

Comment: 1) it's true. 2) it applies to `main` only. 3) you'll have to ask the standards committee for the rationelle. 4) it has always been like that.

Comment: @KerrekSB "cannot call it" Never heard of - and gcc actually allows it. Is that anywhere in the standard?

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes, it is not allowed: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main()` function is guaranteed to return 0 if you do not return explicitly a value.  This is defined in the ISO standard:

> **3.6.1/5:** A `return` statement in `main` has the effect of leaving the `main` function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and
>   calling `std::exit` with the return value as the argument. If control
>   reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the
>   effect is that of executing
>
> `return 0;`

This special behavior is only for `main()`, because `main()` is a function returning an `int`,  and the standard defines the general rule:

> **6.6.3/2** Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a
>   value-returning function.

Now, was it always like that ?  Bjarne Stroutsturp in the *C++ Programming language*, in its edition of 1986, long before any standardization, suggests this. In most of his examples of his tutorial chapter,  `main()`  doesn't return a value, and on page 82 of this early edition, he states:

> Conventionally, main() returns 0 if the program terminates normally
>   and non zero otherwise, so returning the number of errors
>   accomplishes this nicely

***Additional remarks***

In this book, the rule is however implicit from the examples and acompanying explanations; Stroustrup didn't state  explicitly a general unambiguous rule for `main()` nor didn't he mention it in his *The Design and evolution of C++* book of 1994.

To be noted that in C89 the principle was still undefined behavior in absence of explicit return value, until arrival of C99.  But in C++98 the current 0 return by default rule was already formalized. So I think it's not for backward compatibility with C.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it true that in C++ `main ()` is not required to include a `return 0;`?

Yes.

> Does it apply to main only or to any non-void function?

It applies for `main()` only.

> Is it new in C++11 or was it always like that?

No, it always was like that.

> What is the rationale?

Backwards compatibility (and compatibility with C) of the language most probably.

Comment: Do you mean backwards compatibility with C++98?

Comment: @m.rossi I meant in general regarding C dialects.

Comment: Surely not compatibility with standard C. Implicit `return 0` was added in C99 (I think) which is way later than C++ was standardized. I would imagine that the influence was reversed in this case (or the source influence may be shared - say a common compiler extension that made into C++ earlier than into C).

Comment: Is/was `void main` standard in C?  If it is it may have been done to make changing C code into C++ but just having to change the `void` into `int`.

Comment: @NathanOliver It never was. It's an extension of the MSVC compiler.

Comment: OK.  Just wasn't sure.  I am not what you would call a C programmer.

Answer (score 0):

[[basic.start.main]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#5) (emphasis mine):

> *A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function
>   (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling
>   std::exit with the return value as the argument. **If control flows off
>   the end of the compound-statement of main, the effect is equivalent to
>   a return with operand 0** (see also [except.handle]).*

It seems to always have been in the C++ standard (and also in C, for that matter, starting from C99 -see C99 spec §5.1.2.2.3).

It applies to the `main()` function only.

I don't know the original rationale though. It might have been "*to aid developers by saving them from typing `return 0;` at the end of `main()`*".